# Javascript Object to ES6 Classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a javascript plugin written in vanilla javascript in Object Notation

example

```
start = {
  config: {
    a : 1
  },
  core: {
    engine_part1:function() {

    },
    engine_part2: function() {
    } 
  }
  init: function(){

  }
}
```

In this Object Notation the functions can be declare inside `core` ie, engine_part1() and engine_part2()

Is there any workarounds to achieve the same with Javascript Classes?

In Javascript classes the class have datas and functions but I couldn't write functions inside an object like `core` in object notation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your object notation is invalid at `a=1` and `}\ninit:`

Comment: You cannot convert a single instance into a class at all. What's wrong with object notation?

Comment: @Bergi Object Notation is super cool, but i am trying to convert it to ES6 class notation

Comment: @YongQuan Forgive me man, I didn't care about the syntax while posting. Why don't you look into the core idea I asked , instead you are looking into the syntax mistakes

Comment: @CaptainAdmin My point is that objects and classes are two fundamentally different things, and you can't use one's notation for the other.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your explanation. Can i migrate from this object notation to classes? How can I implement functions inside like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) statement to declare your class, then add its properties in the [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) and its ([`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Static_method)) [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Method) in the class' body.

```js
class Start {
  constructor() {
    this.config = {
      a: 1
    };
    
    this.core = {
      engine_part1: () => (console.log('engine_part1')),
      engine_part2: () => (console.log('engine_part2')),
    }
  }
  
  init() {
    console.log('init');
  }
}

const start = new Start;

console.log(start.config);

start.core.engine_part1();
start.init();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Highly appreciate your time taken to answer.

Comment: But I have lot of notations like this so I think it's not a good way to put all this inside constructor

Comment: Not sure to understand what you wanted to say.